# Ansys Parameter Editor max characters

Tags: ansys

I am currently working with the Ansys design modeller and I have a rather complex geometry. In order to compute the required variables for my geometry, I have a very long expression inside my parameter dimension assignment window. Unfortunately it seems to cut off the end of my expressions, resulting in an invalid syntax error for my expression.

[image]

[image]

I cannot reduce the amount of characters inside my formula. Is there a way to split my equation into smaller sub equations or to define some intermediate variables which themself depend on my parameters? What is the best solution to my problem?

Comment: So what does the Ansys help say?

Comment: In the Ansys designmodeler documentation accessible via Ansys help I cannot find any information relating to the allowed length for expressions or any other kind of information that would allow me to solve the problem. It only details how to write the expressions such as supportes characters.

Comment: Bet you have not read all the help files. It was massive even back when we started with it prior to windows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you declared the parameters in DesignModeler you can access them from the project page. Than you could write a python script for the calculation. Here a short example which accesses all parameters and changes their value according to an expression

```
# get parameter object
parms = Parameters.GetAllParameters()
# print the parameter names and replace their values
for i in range(0,parms.Count):
  parmName = parms[i].DisplayText
  try:
    print parmName
    parms[i].Expression = 'Your expression goes here'
  except:
    continue
# refresh the project
Refresh()
```

Of course your expression is limited to IronPythons modules, but on a first glance it looked like your operations are covered in the `math` module

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the parameters' values from other calculators, like MATLAB or online, by inputting the experessions there, and then enter just the values in ANSYS parameter assignment.

Comment: Since I am working on a parameter study, this is not an option. Eventually I will only adjust my first few initial parameters automatically